# How to remove space/blank between any two words using RegexKitLite?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, regex, xcode

I'm wanting to remove a space between any two words and add anything that I want. For example, I'll have a string that has two words in it with a space between the two. I want to be able to remove the space and replace the space with something that I declare. Also, this needs to be written in objective-c or c.

```
NSString *string = @"Word Word2";
```

I'm needing an expression to do this and I can't seem to grasp RegexKitLite. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSString`'s [`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) method:

```
NSString *spaceReplacement = @"whatever";
NSString *replaced = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:spaceReplacement];
```