# Remove the space between two words

Tags: php, regex

How would I remove the spaces between these two "words"

Input:

```
[/TD] [TD="align: left"]
```

Output:

```
[/TD][TD="align: left"]
```

All I know is it needs regex but i don't know anything about it.

Comment: Is this a php string? like `"[/TD][TD=\"align: left\"]"`

Comment: If there's only a single space, why not simply use `$string = str_replace('] [', '', $string);`

Comment: ? I'm trying to get rid of the space between the string. The string is bbcode. The input is exactly what it is and the output I posted is exactly what I need it to be.

Comment: It was downvoted because the question is a "how to do this?" type question. Many folks, including myself, don't feel this question format is optimal for SO.

Comment: Ok. Please downvote: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514853/how-to-remove-space-blank-between-any-two-words-using-regexkitlite?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079341/remove-space-spaces-between-two-words?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26836856/remove-two-or-more-empty-between-space-in-word?rq=1  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570744/remove-extra-spaces-but-not-space-between-two-words?rq=1

Comment: @ShivamPaw It's funny because the first two questions you linked were historical questions with pending close votes about to get closed, and the last two was actually clear and useful, while the last question you linked actually showed effort, where yours doesn't include any of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would just be to remove any spaces between `]` and `[`, if that words for you.

```
$string = '[/TD] [TD="align: left"]';
$string = preg_replace('/\]\s+\[/', '][', $string);
```

Comment: It appears I am going to need to keep the rest of it with spaces, only those specific strings should have the space removed.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only this string you want to alter, a simple str_replace will do the job for you...

```
$string = '[/TD] [TD="align: left"]';

echo str_replace('] [','][',$string);
```

or to save to a new variable

```
$stringnowhite = str_replace('] [','][',$string);
```

Comment: This one will not work if there is more than one space between square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$string = '[/TD] [TD="align: left"]';
$string = preg_replace('/\]\s*\[/', '][', $string);
```